# send XML with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a CentOS 7 server hosting an internal webpage. 
On my webpage I have a button `#test1` once clicked the `test.js` should execute.
`test.js` should make an ajax call to send some XML to my Cisco phone for it to be executed.

I can run a CURL from my server and it works.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @test1.xml -X POST http://username:password@10.0.0.130/CGI/Execute
```

Where text1.xml contains

```
XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="Dial:12345678,,,,,6020197#,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,#"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

Why when I try to run it as a script doesn't it work? I am seeing the following errors.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

document root

```
/var/www/mysite.com/public_html
```

css  index.html  js

**HTML** - index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="googlebot">
    <script src="./js/jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='./js/test.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Auto Bridge Opener</title>
</head>
<body>
     <button name="Log" type="submit" id="test1">Primary Bridge</button></form>
```

**CSS** - style.css

**JS** - test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://username:password@10.0.0.130/CGI/Execute",
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "application/xml",
    data: "<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL='Dial:12345678,,,,,6020197#,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,#'/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>",
    success: function (res) {
        alert("XML: it works!");
    },
    error: function (res) {
        alert("XML: not working! " + res.statusText);
    }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't seemed to have script-included the jQuery library itself.  That would mean `$` isn't defined.

Comment: I sure do, I have a reference here '    <script src="./js/jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' although I using a local copy should I try the CDN?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some issue with you code:
1 For the `$ is not defined`,you should make sure the   `<script src="./js/jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` not got a `404`,and the `jquery-git.js` is a correct jQuery library.
2 The ajax do not support `cross-domain`, so you phone and server should has the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I can perform a CURL and it works, would that not necessarily mean I can use Ajax and it work?

Comment: The `CRUL ` is commend tool,which support many protocol include `http`,in you above code you just send a `http` via it. But the `ajax`, since the security, it do not support cross-domain. If you want send a `http ` and get the response in js without limit,you need use the `jsonp`.

Comment: The `jsonp`'s main usefulness is invode a callback in you js when the response is coming back, but `jsonp` do not support http's `post` method.
Another way is set a `cors` in you phone's `http response head `